# Using git with SSH and (sometimes) corkscrew

Tags: git, ssh, openssh

I need to use git over SSH (it's a self-imposed limitation, but one I am loathe to break).  If my laptop is sitting on my home network, it all works great.  When I'm at work or logged in via VPN, however, I would need to use corkscrew to access my remote repository, which I can set up without problems.

I would like to remain lazy and not specify where I am pulling from/pushing to each time, if possible, so my question is: how can I configure SSH to only use corkscrew when needed (based on, for example, current IP address)?  Alternately, is there a way I can have git detect whether or not to pull from/push to a particular host based on IP address?

Thanks!

Comment: what about a config alias in your ~/.ssh/config ?  call the server ssh config sth like git_host and provide it a Host : fake_host_name, then on your local machine, swap the nameservice / DNS name to match your fake_host_name with "right".  another level of indirection ... and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through my old questions, I realized I resolved this years ago (via questions on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/users/214507/kasperd%20%22kasperd) / [SuperUser](https://serverfault.com/a/889410/21814)) and never posted an answer.

The answer is compliments of [kasperd](https://serverfault.com/users/214507/kasperd%20%22kasperd) over on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/889410/21814).

In your `.ssh/config` use the `Match` keyword to create a conditional section.

The `Match` keyword takes different arguments, one of them is `exec` which will allow you to run an external command and use the return value of that command to decide whether this section applies or not.

You can use that to run a script that inspects whatever network settings you can use to tell the difference between the different networks. The script needs to return `0` when a `ProxyCommand` is needed and any non-zero value when a `ProxyCommand` is not needed.

Here is an example of what the config could look like:

```
Match host external-host.example.com exec /home/joe/bin/need-proxy
  ProxyCommand /home/joe/bin/proxy-script %h %p
```

In my specific case, I just `ping` a machine that I know is only reachable when I'm VPN'd in, and use `ping`'s exit code as `need-proxy`'s exit code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem for myself by setting up a free DynDNS account that points to my server.  Then, I clone via that address.  This means it works wherever I am.  The down side is that even when I am on the same local network as the server, my latop still pulls via DynDNS.

I couldn't come up with a solution that does exactly what you need - setting up multiple remotes and being careful about which one you pull from seemed more complicated than I wanted.

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy